ARM Cortex M7 + tflite-micro: Firmware package leads to hard fault exception
I tried to modify the hello world example of tflite-micro, a tensorflow repository for microcontrollers: https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-micro/tree/main/tensorflow/lite/micro/examples/hello_world
Unfortunately, I can't get it to run smoothly on my Cortex M7 cpu. I built the whole repository via
bazel build -c dbg tensorflow/lite/micro/examples/hello_world:hello_world_test
and then
make -f tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/Makefile TARGET=cortex_m_corstone_300 TARGET_ARCH=cortex-m7+fp test_hello_world_test -j 8
If I try to flash tflite-micro/gen/cortex_m_corstone_300_cortex-m7+fp_default_gcc/bin/hello_world_test via Segger Ozone, it first looks like it works fine (it can flash the image) but then I receive a hard fault with bits FORCED, INVSTATE and IMPRECISERR set to 1. I also tried compiling a very simple hello world program with just a while loop and a counter - same error.
During compilation, I also get these errors:
arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+dp/hard/libg.a(libc_a-fstatr.o): in function `_fstat_r': fstatr.c:(.text._fstat_r+0x12): warning: _fstat is not implemented and will always fail
arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+dp/hard/libg.a(libc_a-signalr.o): in function `_getpid_r': signalr.c:(.text._getpid_r+0x0): warning: _getpid is not implemented and will always fail
arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+dp/hard/libg.a(libc_a-isattyr.o): in function `_isatty_r': isattyr.c:(.text._isatty_r+0xc): warning: _isatty is not implemented and will always fail
arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+dp/hard/libg.a(libc_a-signalr.o): in function `_kill_r': signalr.c:(.text._kill_r+0x12): warning: _kill is not implemented and will always fail
arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+dp/hard/libg.a(libc_a-lseekr.o): in function `_lseek_r': lseekr.c:(.text._lseek_r+0x14): warning: _lseek is not implemented and will always fail
arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: gen/cortex_m_corstone_300_cortex-m7+fp_default_gcc/bin/hello_world_test: section `.data' can't be allocated in segment 0
LOAD: .text .ARM.exidx .copy.table .zero.table .data
arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: warning: gen/cortex_m_corstone_300_cortex-m7+fp_default_gcc/bin/hello_world_test has a LOAD segment with RWX permissions

I have a hard time understanding the build toolchain of tflite so I don't really know where these erros are coming from and how I could fix them. this is my hello_world_test.cpp:
/* Copyright 2023 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
==============================================================================*/


#include <math.h>
#include "tensorflow/lite/core/c/common.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/examples/hello_world/models/modelData.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_interpreter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_log.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_mutable_op_resolver.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_profiler.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/recording_micro_interpreter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/system_setup.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/schema/schema_generated.h"

volatile float prediction = 0.0f;

TfLiteStatus RegisterOps(tflite::MicroMutableOpResolver<2>& op_resolver)
{
  TF_LITE_ENSURE_STATUS( op_resolver.AddFullyConnected() );
  TF_LITE_ENSURE_STATUS( op_resolver.AddLogistic() );
  return kTfLiteOk;
}

float LoadFloatModelAndPerformInference()
{
  const tflite::Model* model = ::tflite::GetModel( tfliteModel );
  TFLITE_CHECK_EQ( model->version(), TFLITE_SCHEMA_VERSION );

  tflite::MicroMutableOpResolver<2> op_resolver;
  TF_LITE_ENSURE_STATUS( RegisterOps( op_resolver ) );

  // Arena size just a round number. The exact arena usage can be determined
  // using the RecordingMicroInterpreter.
  constexpr int kTensorArenaSize = 3000;
  uint8_t tensor_arena[ kTensorArenaSize ];

  tflite::MicroInterpreter interpreter( model, op_resolver, tensor_arena, kTensorArenaSize );
  TF_LITE_ENSURE_STATUS( interpreter.AllocateTensors() );

  constexpr int kNumTestValues = 2;
  float inputs[ kNumTestValues ] = { 0.0f, 0.0f };

  interpreter.input(0)->data.f[0] = inputs[0];
  interpreter.input(0)->data.f[1] = inputs[1];
  TF_LITE_ENSURE_STATUS( interpreter.Invoke() );
  float y_pred = interpreter.output(0)->data.f[0];

  return y_pred;
}

int main( )
{
  tflite::InitializeTarget();
  while( true )
  {
    prediction = LoadFloatModelAndPerformInference();
  }
  return 0;
}

